# How do you see, set, and access variables in IntelliJ so that it can be passed from one plug-in to system properties?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Have a GitHub plug-in in IntelliJ. It knows the branch that is being worked on.

How would you get that branch name and add it into the system properties used when launching a server in the IDE?

This would be the equivalent of something like:

```sh
-Dthevariableforbranchnumber=${some.branch.number}
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for [variables in the parameters of the run/debug configurations](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74031) was added recently, but there is no variable for the branch number.

There is also a related request to add [branch to the live templates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155840).

You are welcome to submit a new request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA to provide a variable with the VCS branch for the run configuration.

Still not clear how it will work if the project has multiple VCS roots with different branches.